# Are there any ways to get data from ref as a list in java

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am creating an android app to make food order , so I cannot access to items of my child in realtime database.How can I get them as a list or seperately ?

whenever I try something app is just automatically close itself , so there I know that something went wrong

Comment: If the app crashes, there is an error message and a stack trace in your logcat output. Dig those up, and add them together with the [minimal code that reproduces the problem to you question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to drastically improve the chances that someone can help you troubleshoot the problem.

Comment: Please add what Frank van Puffelen asked for and please also responde with @.

Answer (score 0):

you can use **addValueEventListener()** function to get data as a snapshot. By doing that you can iterate the snapshot data and add to an array list. The following is a some example that I have done to get data from reference

```
private void readUsers() {

    final List<User> mUsers= new ArrayList<>();
    final FirebaseUser firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");

    reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                mUsers.clear();
                for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    User user = snapshot.getValue(User.class);

                    assert user != null;
                    assert firebaseUser != null;

                    if (!user.getId().equals(firebaseUser.getUid())) {
                        mUsers.add(user);
                    }
                }

                userAdaptor = new UserAdaptor(getContext(), mUsers, false);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(userAdaptor);

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```